# Client Sending Big String (BASE64 Image) from server to client

Tags: java, c#, sockets, server

I have a problem in communication between client and server through socket.
Java server and the client in C#. When I send a String Base64 type image to my C# client my program crashes because of the size of string.

```
void ecouteur(string commande) {

        try {
            IPEndPoint   ip = new IPEndPoint (IPAddress.Parse ("127.0.0.1"), 1234);
            System.Net.Sockets.Socket sock = new System.Net.Sockets.Socket (AddressFamily.InterNetwork, SocketType.Stream, ProtocolType.Tcp);
            sock.Connect (ip);
            byte[] data = new byte[2024];
            int receivedDataLength = sock.Receive (data);
            String temp = Base64Decode( Encoding.ASCII.GetString (data, 0, receivedDataLength));



            sock.Shutdown (SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close ();

        } catch (SocketException e1) {

            Console.WriteLine ("****Unable to connect to server.****\n" + e1);
            //sock.Shutdown (SocketShutdown.Both);
            sock.Close ();
        }
}
```

Comment: Why are you using strings to move the data? The data is plainly binary, and should be sent in a binary format. As an aside, it's unlikely that you'll receive all the data in a single `Receive` as you try to above. A single call to `Receive` might only yield a single byte of a stream of data that could be considerably longer.

Comment: It seems very unlikely to me that the code above will "crash because of the size of string", given that the string will, at maximum, be 2048 bytes. What's more likely is that you're quitting before everything arrives. You'll need to do multiple receives, and also have some sort of protocol to indicate when the full data is completely received. This might mean sending a length field before the payload, or perhaps closing the connection to indicate completion. Why not use HTTP?

Comment: See [this](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/86759/receiving-all-data-comes-from-web-in-system-net-socket)